# Disable VB6 Timer during updates

Tags: vb6

How do I execute my **timer1.enabled=true** after TreeView FOR statement has reached the last item. My timer starts counting while the treeview is working still.

This is the code I have so far.

```
Private Sub Command17_Click()
    Dim objRootNode As Node
    Dim objChildNode As Node
    Dim iRootCounter As Integer
    Dim iChildCounter As Integer
    Dim countt As Integer
    Dim ii As Integer

    For iRootCounter = 1 To TreeView2.Nodes.Count

        ii = TreeView2.Nodes(iRootCounter).Index

        Set objRootNode = TreeView2.Nodes(iRootCounter)

        If objRootNode.Image = 4 Then

            Set objChildNode = objRootNode.Child ' Gets first child

            For iChildCounter = 1 To objRootNode.Children

                If objChildNode.Image = 3 Then
                    objRootNode.Image = 9
                End If

                Set objChildNode = objChildNode.Next ' Get next node

            Next

        End If

        If TreeView2.Nodes(iRootCounter).Index = TreeView2.Nodes.Count - 0 Then
            If startt = True Then
                Timer1.Enabled = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

When I run this code, the treeview items remain in processing mode, meaning it's still doing its job changing image index for each item after I run another code, then this button gets triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Timer1.Enabled = False` at the beginning of the TreeView update. Then, set it back to True before exiting.

Better yet, stop the timer in the `Timer1_Timer` event handler:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()

    ' Stop timer until all code is execute
    Timer1.Enabled = False

    Command17_Click

    ' Restart timer
    Timer1.Enabled = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `_Timer()` events aren't re-entrant, so disable/re-enable inside one shouldn't do anything... right?

Comment: Indeed but if the `Interval` is shorter than the time it takes to execute the code in the event handler, calls are going to stack up. Disabling the timer will prevent this.

Comment: As I understand it, `_Timer()` events don't stack up. Multiple messages are not enqueued, they're dropped (or rather, subsumed into a single event). I do think it's prudent to disable the timer inside the update, but I don't think doing so in the `_Timer()` event does anything useful.